# snap program icon not visible in the taskbar and super

Tags: snap, gui, taskbar

[image: invisible]

ubuntu 20.04
after an update the brave browser icon is not visible; both in taskbar and super. it is a snap package.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on the empty icon and click unpin. Then click activities ---> rightclick on Brave Browser ---> add to panel. Now it should show the icon. That is how I do it in Kubuntu. It might be a little bit different in Ubuntu. The principle would be the same though.

Background info: You should be able to find the icon in `/snap/brave/current`. It probably is called `icon.png`.